# eslint not recognizing template literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, template-literals

```
const perunString = perun.times(100).toFixed(2).toString();
return `%{perunString} %`;
```

Which gives two errors

1. 'perunString' is defined but never used
2. Strings must use single quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your template interpolation syntax that is probably causing both errors:

```
// Before
`%{perunString} %`

// After
`${perunString} %`
```

Note the change from `%{` to `${`.

Comment: Nope, I want perunString included and then a percent sign at the end

Comment: Sorry, tried to set the ecmaversion but it didnt fix

Comment: @Aakil Updated. So you mean to have: `\`${perunString} %\``?

Comment: Ahhhh, I meant to have a dollar sign, not a percent sign. Sorry. Can you edit your ansswer to just that? The ecmascriptversion was already correct and not the issue

Comment: Sure, I started answering with that based on the "not recognizing" in the title before realizing that recognition of the template string wasn't the problem.