# Why doesn't atom package linter-eslint recognize template literals?

Tags: ecmascript-6, atom-editor, eslint, template-literals

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) on template literals for ES6 has the following syntax example:

```
`string text ${expression} string text`
```

Following this, my function is:

```
function madLib (verb, adjective, noun) {
    return `We shall ${verb} the ${adjective} ${noun}.`;
}
```

In console, this outputs as expected:

```
We shall fly the iridescent zoo.
```

However, the eslinter package complains of a fatal parsing error at the first back tick, citing

```
Unexpected character '`'
```

Why is this?

(This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162158/eslint-not-recognizing-template-literal) on literals is about a syntax error--couldn't find any other related eslinter posts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESLint by default is configured to only lint ES5 code. Template literals are part of ES6 spec. Because of that, parser will fail to parse your JavaScript code with fatal error. You need to create an `.eslintrc` file in the root of your project and set `ecmaVersion` to 6. For more information about configuring ESLint see  http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options

Comment: Worked, thanks! Another one for you Ilya, ESLint is still giving me grief over default argument assignment, e.g. `function myFunction (name = 'hello') { return name; }`. It says `Unexpected character '='`. Is this not covered by changing the `ecmaVersion` version to 6?

Comment: That should work once you enable ES6. Default parameters are part of the ES6 spec.

Answer (score 0):

this is the way you can. in the .eslintrc.js change the values of "quotes" (for me is single) like this:

```
"quotes": ["error", "single", {
        avoidEscape: true,
        allowTemplateLiterals: true
    }],
```

you can use back-tick and avoid escaping!